# Select the last element of an Array in a DataFrame

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm working on a project and I'm dealing with some nested JSON date with a complicated schema/data structure. Basically what I want to do is filter out one of the columns, in a dataframe, such that I select the last element in the array. I'm totally stuck on how to do this. I hope this make sense.

Below is an example of what I'm trying to accomplish:

```
val singersDF = Seq(
  ("beatles", "help,hey,jude"),
  ("romeo", "eres,mia"),
  ("elvis", "this,is,an,example")
).toDF("name", "hit_songs")

val actualDF = singersDF.withColumn(
  "hit_songs",
  split(col("hit_songs"), "\\,")
)

actualDF.show(false)
actualDF.printSchema() 

+-------+-----------------------+
|name   |hit_songs              |
+-------+-----------------------+
|beatles|[help, hey, jude]      |
|romeo  |[eres, mia]            |
|elvis  |[this, is, an, example]|
+-------+-----------------------+
root
 |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- hit_songs: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
```

The end goal for the output would be the following, to select the last "string" in the hit_songs array.

I'm not worried about what the schema would look like afterwards.

```
+-------+---------+
|name   |hit_songs|
+-------+---------+
|beatles|jude     |
|romeo  |mia      |
|elvis  |example  |
+-------+---------+
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the `size` function to calculate the index of the desired item in the array, and then pass this as the argument of `Column.apply` (explicitly or implicitly):

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import spark.implicits._

actualDF.withColumn("hit_songs", $"hit_songs".apply(size($"hit_songs").minus(1)))
```

Or:

```
actualDF.withColumn("hit_songs", $"hit_songs"(size($"hit_songs").minus(1)))
```

Answer (score 10):

Since **spark 2.4+**, you can use [element_at](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/#element_at) which supports negative indexing. As you can see in this documentation quote:

> element_at(array, index) - Returns element of array at given (1-based) index. If index < 0, accesses elements from the last to the first. Returns NULL if the index exceeds the length of the array.

With that, here's how to get the last element:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.element_at
actualDF.withColumn("hit_songs", element_at($"hit_songs", -1))
```

---

#### Reproducible example:

First let's prepare a sample dataframe with an array column:

```
val columns = Seq("col1")
val data = Seq((Array(1,2,3)))
val rdd = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(data)
val df = rdd.toDF(columns:_*)
```

which looks like this:

```
scala> df.show()
+---------+
|     col1|
+---------+
|[1, 2, 3]|
+---------+
```

Then, apply `element_at` to get the last element as follows:

```
scala> df.withColumn("last_value", element_at($"col1", -1)).show()
+---------+----------+
|     col1|last_value|
+---------+----------+
|[1, 2, 3]|         3|
+---------+----------+
```

Comment: to the best of your knowledge does this directly access the last element of the array, or is it just syntactic sugar for calculating the size and getting the element at position size - 1? Asking because I want to access the last element several times and I would rather calculate the size of the array once and save it as a new column, then have element_at repeat that calculation many times

Answer (score 5):

Here's one approach:

```
val actualDF = Seq(
  ("beatles", Seq("help", "hey", "jude")),
  ("romeo", Seq("eres", "mia")),
  ("elvis", Seq("this", "is", "an", "example"))
).toDF("name", "hit_songs")

import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

actualDF.withColumn("total_songs", size($"hit_songs")).
  select($"name", $"hit_songs"($"total_songs" - 1).as("last_song"))
// +-------+---------+
// |   name|last_song|
// +-------+---------+
// |beatles|     jude|
// |  romeo|      mia|
// |  elvis|  example|
// +-------+---------+
```

Answer (score 4):

You are looking for the SparkSQL function [`slice`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/#slice). or this [PySpark Source](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html?highlight=substring#pyspark.sql.functions.slice).

Your implementation in Scala `slice($"hit_songs", -1, 1)(0)` where `-1` is the starting position (last index) and `1` is the length, and `(0)` extracts the first string from resulting array of exactly 1 element.

**Full Example:**

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val singersDF = Seq(
  ("beatles", "help,hey,jude"),
  ("romeo", "eres,mia"),
  ("elvis", "this,is,an,example")
).toDF("name", "hit_songs")

val actualDF = singersDF.withColumn(
  "hit_songs",
  split(col("hit_songs"), "\\,")
)

val newDF = actualDF.withColumn("last_song", slice($"hit_songs", -1, 1)(0))

display(newDF)
```

**Output:**

```
+---------+------------------------------+-------------+
|  name   |          hit_songs           |  last_song  |
+---------+------------------------------+-------------+
| beatles | ["help","hey","jude"]        | jude        |
| romeo   | ["eres","mia"]               | mia         |
| elvis   | ["this","is","an","example"] | example     |
+---------+------------------------------+-------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use an UDF like:

```
val lastElementUDF = udf((array: Seq[String]) => array.lastOption)

actualDF.withColumn("hit_songs", lastElementUDF($"hit_songs"))
```

`array.lastOption` will return `None` or `Some`, and `array.last` will throw an exception if the array is empty.