# substring from lastIndexOf in spark scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a column in my dataframe which contains the filename

```
test_1_1_1_202012010101101
```

I want to get the string after the lastIndexOf(_)
I tried this and it is working

```
val timestamp_df =file_name_df.withColumn("timestamp",split(col("filename"),"_").getItem(4))
```

But I want to make it more generic, so that if in future if the filename can have any number of _ in it, it can split it on the basis of lastIndexOf _

```
val timestamp_df =file_name_df.withColumn("timestamp", expr("substring(filename, length(filename)-15,17)"))
```

This also is not generic as the character length can vary.

Can anyone help me in using the lastIndexOf function with withColumn.

Comment: try : `reverse(split(col("filename"),"_")).getItem(0)`

Comment: Also relevant : https://stackoverflow.com/a/60317779/2928853

Comment: reverse is not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
val timestamp_df =file_name_df.withColumn("timestamp",reverse(split(reverse(col("filename")),"_").getItem(0)))
```

It's working with this.

Comment: using two reverse is counter intuitive when you can use one element_at -1(last value). if you are using spark 2.4, element_at will be the most performant solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **`element_at`** function with **`split`** to get last element of array.

**`Example:`**

```
df.withColumn("timestamp",element_at(split(col("filename"),"_"),-1)).show(false)
+--------------------------+---------------+
|filename                  |timestamp      |
+--------------------------+---------------+
|test_1_1_1_202012010101101|202012010101101|
+--------------------------+---------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `substring_index`

```scala
scala> val df = Seq(("a-b-c", 1),("d-ef-foi",2)).toDF("c1","c2")
df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [c1: string, c2: int]

+--------+---+
|      c1| c2|
+--------+---+
|   a-b-c|  1|
|d-ef-foi|  2|
+--------+---+

scala> df.withColumn("c3", substring_index(col("c1"), "-", -1)).show
+--------+---+---+
|      c1| c2| c3|
+--------+---+---+
|   a-b-c|  1|  c|
|d-ef-foi|  2|foi|
+--------+---+---+
```

Per [docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/api/sql/index.html#substring_index): When the last argument "is negative, everything to the right of the final delimiter (counting from the right) is returned"